# Why doesn't this nested loop work?

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a list of triangular numbers (numbers that are the sum of previous numbers 3 = 2 + 1, 6 = 3 + 2 + 1 etc.) But for some reason, the nested loop never get iterated

```
triangulars = []
for i in range(1, 1000):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(i, 0):
        sum += j
triangulars.append(sum)  
print(triangulars)
```

Answer (score 2):

because `range(i,0)` is empty when `i >= 0`

change `for j in range(i,0)` to  `for j in range(i,0,-1)`

Comment: range(i,0) is empty when i **>=** 0

Answer (score 1):

Also you'll need to push the `triangulars.append(sum)` inside the first loop(for i ...).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two small bugs in your code. First `range(i, 0)` is going to return an empty list if `i >= 0`, maybe you want `range(0, i)` or `range(i, 0, step=-1)`, I think in this case either of those would work. Second it looks like your indentation is off on the line `triangulars.append(sum)`. Right now it's outside both loops, I think you want it inside the first loop.

Also you don't need a double loop for this problem, you can just do something like:

```
def make_triangulars(N):
    triangulars = []
    last = 0
    for i in range(1, N):
        last += i
        triangulars.append(last)
    return triangulars
```